# Chrome Debugger Paused

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome, debugging, google-chrome-devtools

I need help. I encounter this problem that when I edit some code in SCSS, the source keeps opening and it states that the debugger is paused. I need to click it before it applies the code.

Chrome Debugger paused photo:
[image: Chrome Debugger paused photo]

Answer (score 0):

If you scroll down the right panel, you should see a `Breakpoints` section. Uncheck all of the entries below this section and you should be fine.

See: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/breakpoints